# C++ simple brute force project password input method

Tags: html, c++, c++11, passwords, brute-force

I am trying to create a simple C++ brute forcing program to crack small passwords-maybe like 3-4 characters long, (as a science fair project) just to show people how it works, i.e. my topic is mainly about cyber security and data breach vulnerability and stuff.

So I got the brute forcing part covered, but what I want to change is that instead of asking users to enter their password within my program itself, I was wondering if it was possible to make a, say, an HTML page with a login screen, and the entered password is then saved to a txt file which I can then open from my program for the brute forcing part.

What I am trying to say is that most people trying this out wont be so convinced entering passwords into an output box. They might wonder if I had just printed out the password they entered. I saw other people's programs but all they did was cin>>password and then started the brute forcing part. The user does not know if his password was cracked or the programmer just did cout<< password.

So it would help me a lot by letting me know of methods in which I can achieve this(not just with HTML, anything is fine, as long as its not an output box).

Sorry for the long question! Just wanted to make sure I covered all the info.
Please help me!!!
P.S: I'm just a student (1 and a half years into C++ :)), so please try to keep it as simple as you can. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It seems your question has nothing to do with C++. You are asking how to create a web page which stores data in a text file (and that is already too broad for Stack Overflow). The fact that you later process the file with C++ is irrelevant. Try to focus more on the actual question and think about which technology context is necessary and which isn't.

Comment: I'm sorry if this has been posted in the wrong category but could you tell me more about whether it is possible to create a webpage that stores data in a text file (as you mentioned), and if so, how?

Comment: That question is *almost* as broad as "how can I write data into a text file?" or "how can I create a web page?" (seriously, I am not joking!). Do you know any appropriate server-side web page technologies? PHP? CGI? Node.js? You basically need a server which processes an HTTP POST request, with the data you want to store as a parameter to the request. Then that server can, e.g., forward the data to a program which stores the data in a file. Or it could even forward it directly to your C++ program. Or the C++ program itself can contain an HTTP server. There are a million ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply print out as much internal information in the terminal/outputbox as possible. This way, people get a better understanding of the inner workings of your program. For example, you could print out every password that your program tried. On top of that, show your sourcecode to the people who are also interested in that.